# Is it impossible to index a document where a property has multiple fields, one of them being a completion type with contexts?

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my mapping (some fields renamed/removed), I'm using ES 6.0

```
{
    "mappings": {
      "_doc" :{
        "properties" : {
            "username" : {
                "type": "keyword",
                "fields": {
                  "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion",
                    "contexts": [
                      { 
                        "name": "user_id",
                        "type": "category"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
            },
            "user_id": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Now when I try to index a document with

```
PUT usernames/_doc/1
{
  "username" : "JOHN",
  "user_id": 1
}
```

OR

```
PUT usernames/_doc/1
{
  "username" : {
    "input": "JOHN",
    "contexts: {
      "user_id": 1
    }
  }
  "user_id": 1
}
```

The first doesn't index with context and the second just fails. I've attempted to add a path like so,

```
{
    "mappings": {
      "_doc" :{
        "properties" : {
            "username" : {
                "type": "keyword",
                "fields": {
                  "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion",
                    "contexts": [
                      { 
                        "name": "user_id",
                        "type": "category",
                        "path": "user_id",
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
            },
            "user_id": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

And attempting indexing again

```
PUT usernames/_doc/1
{
  "username" : "JOHN",
  "user_id": 1
}
```

But it just throws a context must be a keyword or text error. Do I have to give up and make a totally new property username-autocomplete instead? Or is there some magical way where I can have a context completion suggester and another field on the same property, and be able to index like I would other multifield properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is the right one (i.e. with the path inside the context), but you need to set the `user_id` field as a `keyword` and it will work:

```
{
    "mappings": {
      "_doc" :{
        "properties" : {
            "username" : {
                "type": "keyword",
                "fields": {
                  "suggest" : {
                    "type" : "completion",
                    "contexts": [
                      { 
                        "name": "user_id",
                        "type": "category",
                        "path": "user_id",
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
            },
            "user_id": {
              "type": "keyword"         <--- change this
            }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Then you can index your document without creating an additional field, like this:

```
PUT usernames/_doc/1
{
  "username" : "JOHN",
  "user_id": "1"                        <--- wrap in double quotes
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Is the downside of this method not being able to specify a weight to the suggestion during index-time?Would I still be able to update the document for a weight?